# DocumentId : string or Int?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am confused on the requirements for the DocumentId member in Document.
As the C# SDK depicts, it expected to have a string. However,when I use my string "DOCUMENT-624", here is the error message I receive the below error
So if we can assign a string, how come an integer is expected ?

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute]
public class Document : IEquatable<Document>
{

    public Document();
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Name = "documentId", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

> Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
>
> "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
>
> "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter.
>   The documentId specified is not a positive integer."
>
> }

Comment: Different code bases, but I use DocuSign in Salesforce and it lists the property as an int.

Comment: Interesting, do you use DocuSign in SalesForce via a GUI or an actual programming language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please send an int as a string. Eg "1"

The over use of strings is a vestige of the xml data format.

Comment: I suppose I don't have the choice. It's confusing at first but I understand it is a vestige of xml format. Thanks!